# how to represent functions and global variables in UML?

Tags: c++, uml, functions, modeling

I'm going to translate into UML a C++ project I have been doing for a few days and which I estimate convenient to handle as a model for a way better management. The problem is the following: I tried to define a singleton to store precalculated values, it didn't work and the best solution ended to be declaring a static global scope variable with two functions, one to add data and other to search such data. How can I model functions and variables in a namespace?

I thought of representing the global variable as an object and the functions as interfaces. However I really have no idea of what to do.

**Note:** I have tried many ways to include those three elements inside a class or a struct but it has been imposible to make them work as intended.

Comment: Regarding representing global variables and free functions using the class notation: in UML, you can represent static members (as opposed to instance members) by underlining member names (see [here](http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dab/cs1410/textbook/9.Classes_And_Objects/static.html)), so you can model globals like that. Another thing you can do is to use a *custom stereotype* (the `<< ... >>` thing) on the class itself, e.g. `<< static >>` or `<< globals >>` to modify the meaning of the element (just explain it in some accompanying text). Stereotypes are there to allow you to extend UML.

Comment: If you need to indicate that some other code depends on that pseudo class, then you can use a generalized dependency (a dashed arrow) `- - - - ->`, as that doesn't imply that the dependent end holds a reference, just that the names of the global functions and/or the global variable are mentioned somehow.

Comment: _@Miguel_ Somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663462/uml-representation-for-c-c-function-pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UML is not a graphical programming language. Transforming C++ in UML will do no magic in this regard.

### Recommendation

- The first thing that you need to do, is to reconsider your problem and find out what is worth to show visually and what
  you expect from the visualization.
- At the same time, if you have a lot of static global variables, your source code encapsulated some internals at the level of the compilation unit.  So even if you have no objects and classes, you have somehow a component and could see your source file as component.
- Now, if you manage to do this, one step further could be to consider the component as an instance of a class. This could allow you to start introducing some OO design into a bunch of free standing jungle of functions.
- Alternatively, you could consider every freestanding function as a stateless class. But this might lead to an overkill and bring us back to the question if visual programming is really a good idea for your problem.

### How UML can help?

If you want to show the **flow of control**, that starting with some [objects](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-objects.html) gets some behaviors and generates a flow of objects, you may consider using an [activity diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html). Functions would be [actions](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-actions.html):

- but you might just end up with a kind of more elaborate flowchart diagram : you might express with more work things that could be easier expressed in code;
- on the other side, viewing a very complex flow may allow to better understand how the parts relate together, and even identify parallelisation opportunities.

If you want to show the **structure** of your module, and the exposed API, you may consider:

- a [component diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html) could help you to abstract the interface and purpose of your different modules or submodules (e.g. compilation units);
- a [composite structure](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composite-structure-diagrams.html) may focus on the inner structure of your modules: the parts may represent named objects (variables). But  nothing is foreseen for functions, so you’d need to handle them as a parts as well. I’m not sure that it’s the best thing in your case
- a class diagram could be used to show how the static globals relate to a group of related functions, especially if these are
  embedded in their own namespace.

Personally, from what I understand of the partial information on your case, I’d opt for the last approach: even if you would have no `class` in your implementation, at a conceptual level they seem to be there. And this could then help to develop a more object oriented design, breaking down larger modules in smaller "classes", focusing on their public interface, and making them interchangeable.

Comment: TBF people certainly have tried to use UML as a graphical programming lanuage - its is generaly considered to have been a bad idea though